# Why does Visual Studio not show Project/Target Performance Summary in Output window?

Tags: visual-studio, performance, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

If I build a simple .NET 8.0 HelloWorld project in Visual Studio 2022, I get the following output in my output window:

```
Rebuild started at 14:53...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: HelloWorldNew, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored C:\Users\John.Doe\source\repos\HelloWorldNew\HelloWorldNew\HelloWorldNew.csproj (in 0,8 ms).
1>HelloWorldNew -> C:\Users\John.Doe\source\repos\HelloWorldNew\HelloWorldNew\bin\Debug\net8.0\HelloWorldNew.dll
1>
1>Project Performance Summary:
1>      277 ms  C:\Users\John.Doe\source\repos\HelloWorldNew\HelloWorldNew\HelloWorldNew.csproj   1 calls
1>
1>Target Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  ResGen                                     1 calls
1>        0 ms  AddSourceRevisionToInformationalVersion    1 calls
1>        0 ms  InitializeSourceControlInformation         1 calls
1>        0 ms  _InitializeSourceControlInformationFromSourceControlManager   1 calls
1>        0 ms  TranslateBitbucketGitUrlsInSourceControlInformation   1 calls
1>        0 ms  TranslateAzureReposGitUrlsInSourceControlInformation   1 calls
1>        0 ms  TranslateGitLabUrlsInSourceControlInformation   1 calls
1>        0 ms  TranslateGitHubUrlsInSourceControlInformation   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _SourceLinkHasSingleProvider               1 calls
1>        0 ms  InitializeSourceControlInformationFromSourceControlManager   1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute    1 calls
1>        0 ms  _SetTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute        1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFile            1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFileCore        1 calls
1>        0 ms  GetAssemblyAttributes                      1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFileShouldRun   1 calls
1>        0 ms  SetWin32ManifestProperties                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  _SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties        1 calls
1>        0 ms  PrepareResources                           1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterRebuild                               1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterResGen                                1 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreResGen                                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeResGen                               1 calls
1>        0 ms  PrepareResourceNames                       1 calls
1>        0 ms  CreateCustomManifestResourceNames          1 calls
1>        0 ms  SplitResourcesByCulture                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  _ComputeNETCoreBuildOutputFiles            1 calls
1>        0 ms  _ChooseAppHost                             1 calls
1>        0 ms  CopyAdditionalFiles                        1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateCompileInputs                     1 calls
1>        0 ms  ExpressionBuildExtension                   1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateAssemblyInfo                       1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateCompiledExpressionsTempFile        1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckContainersPackage                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  Build                                      1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  PrepareForRun                              1 calls
1>        0 ms  _ComputeUserRuntimeAssemblies              1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForCompileOutputs                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory          1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromThisProject   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromTransitiveProjectReferences   1 calls
1>        0 ms  AddDepsJsonAndRuntimeConfigToCopyItemsForReferencingProjects   1 calls
1>        0 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryXamlAppDefs        1 calls
1>        0 ms  _PopulateCommonStateForGetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems   1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeCompile                              1 calls
1>        0 ms  GetTargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker     1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateSatelliteAssemblyInputs           1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterCompile                               1 calls
1>        0 ms  _ReportUpgradeNetAnalyzersNuGetWarning     1 calls
1>        0 ms  AddGlobalAnalyzerConfigForPackage_MicrosoftCodeAnalysisNetAnalyzers   1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateSourceLinkFile                     1 calls
1>        0 ms  _InitializeSourceRootMappedPathsFromSourceControl   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _SetSourceLinkFilePath                     1 calls
1>        0 ms  _SetEmbeddedFilesFromSourceControlManagerUntrackedFiles   1 calls
1>        0 ms  PreXsdCodeGen                              1 calls
1>        0 ms  _ComputeSkipAnalyzers                      1 calls
1>        0 ms  AddImplicitDefineConstants                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  _BeforeVBCSCoreCompile                     1 calls
1>        0 ms  DesignTimeXamlMarkupCompilation            1 calls
1>        0 ms  CreateSatelliteAssemblies                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  ValidationExtension                        1 calls
1>        0 ms  Rebuild                                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  IgnoreJavaScriptOutputAssembly             1 calls
1>        0 ms  CleanReferencedProjects                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  PrepareProjectReferences                   1 calls
1>        0 ms  ValidateExecutableReferences               1 calls
1>        0 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _AddOutputPathToGlobalPropertiesToRemove   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _AddMicrosoftNetCompilerToolsetFrameworkPackage   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence     1 calls
1>        0 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild         1 calls
1>        0 ms  IncludeTransitiveProjectReferences         1 calls
1>        0 ms  CleanPublishFolder                         1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForObsoleteDotNetCliToolReferences   1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveLockFileCopyLocalFiles              1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveLockFileAnalyzers                   1 calls
1>        0 ms  CheckForDuplicateItems                     1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveLockFileReferences                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  ValidateCommandLineProperties              1 calls
1>        0 ms  _ComputePackageReferencePublish            1 calls
1>        0 ms  _SdkBeforeRebuild                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  _DefaultMicrosoftNETPlatformLibrary        1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveReferences                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeRebuild                              1 calls
1>        0 ms  EnableIntermediateOutputPathMismatchWarning   1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeClean                                1 calls
1>        0 ms  _SdkBeforeClean                            1 calls
1>        0 ms  Clean                                      1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterResolveReferences                     1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateFakes                              1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeGenerateFakesAssemblies              1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedNETCoreVersion         1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedCppNETCoreVersion      1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedArtifactsPath          1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveOffByDefaultAnalyzers               1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedHostingUsage           1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckAndUnsetUnsupportedPrefer32Bit       1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterClean                                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  ExpandSDKReferences                        1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveSDKReferences                       1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                   1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeResolveReferences                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GetProjectJsonPath                        1 calls
1>        0 ms  PrepareForBuild                            1 calls
1>        0 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  GetFrameworkPaths                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeBuild                                1 calls
1>        0 ms  CleanXsdCodeGen                            1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForLanguageAndFeatureCombinationSupport   1 calls
1>        1 ms  GetAssemblyVersion                         1 calls
1>        1 ms  _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites         1 calls
1>        1 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          1 calls
1>        1 ms  _CollectTargetFrameworkForTelemetry        1 calls
1>        1 ms  SourceControlManagerPublishTranslatedUrls   1 calls
1>        1 ms  GetTargetPath                              1 calls
1>        1 ms  GenerateGlobalUsings                       1 calls
1>        1 ms  _ComputeToolPackInputsToProcessFrameworkReferences   1 calls
1>        1 ms  _GetRestoreProjectStyle                    1 calls
1>        1 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              1 calls
1>        1 ms  _InitializeGitHubSourceLinkUrl             1 calls
1>        1 ms  SetEmbeddedFilesFromSourceControlManagerUntrackedFiles   1 calls
1>        1 ms  ProcessFrameworkReferences                 1 calls
1>        1 ms  AssignTargetPaths                          1 calls
1>        1 ms  InitializeSourceRootMappedPaths            1 calls
1>        1 ms  _InitializeSourceRootMappedPathsOpt        1 calls
1>        1 ms  CollectPackageReferences                   1 calls
1>        1 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 calls
1>        1 ms  GenerateNETCompatibleDefineConstants       1 calls
1>        1 ms  _GetAppHostPaths                           1 calls
1>        1 ms  _GenerateCompileDependencyCache            1 calls
1>        1 ms  ResolvePackageAssets                       1 calls
1>        1 ms  _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties   1 calls
1>        1 ms  _ComputeReferenceAssemblies                1 calls
1>        1 ms  CreateGeneratedAssemblyInfoInputsCacheFile   1 calls
1>        1 ms  Compile                                    1 calls
1>        1 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedAppHostUsage           1 calls
1>        2 ms  _InitializeGitLabSourceLinkUrl             1 calls
1>        2 ms  _HandlePackageFileConflicts                1 calls
1>        2 ms  _InitializeAzureReposGitSourceLinkUrl      1 calls
1>        2 ms  IncrementalClean                           1 calls
1>        2 ms  _InitializeBitbucketGitSourceLinkUrl       1 calls
1>        2 ms  _GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFilesInputCache   1 calls
1>        2 ms  _BlockWinMDsOnUnsupportedTFMs              1 calls
1>        2 ms  ResolveFrameworkReferences                 1 calls
1>        3 ms  CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo                   1 calls
1>        3 ms  _GenerateSourceLinkFile                    1 calls
1>        5 ms  ResolveTargetingPackAssets                 1 calls
1>        5 ms  _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory   1 calls
1>        6 ms  CopyFilesToOutputDirectory                 1 calls
1>        7 ms  CoreClean                                  1 calls
1>        8 ms  FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences       1 calls
1>        8 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                  1 calls
1>       19 ms  GenerateBuildRuntimeConfigurationFiles     1 calls
1>       48 ms  _CreateAppHost                             1 calls
1>       58 ms  GenerateBuildDependencyFile                1 calls
1>       58 ms  CoreCompile                                1 calls
1>
1>Task Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  AllowEmptyTelemetry                        1 calls
1>        0 ms  ValidateExecutableReferences               1 calls
1>        0 ms  FindAppConfigFile                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateGlobalUsings                       1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveFrameworkReferences                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  AssignTargetPath                           7 calls
1>        0 ms  AssignCulture                              1 calls
1>        0 ms  SetRidAgnosticValueForProjects             1 calls
1>        0 ms  GetFrameworkPath                           1 calls
1>        0 ms  Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.LocateRepository   1 calls
1>        0 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.Common.SourceLinkHasSingleProvider   1 calls
1>        0 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.TranslateRepositoryUrls   1 calls
1>        0 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.GitLab.TranslateRepositoryUrls   1 calls
1>        0 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git.TranslateRepositoryUrls   1 calls
1>        0 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.Bitbucket.Git.TranslateRepositoryUrls   1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig                1 calls
1>        0 ms  MSBuild                                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  ConvertToAbsolutePath                      1 calls
1>        0 ms  JoinItems                                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolvePackageAssets                       1 calls
1>        0 ms  MakeDir                                    2 calls
1>        0 ms  RemoveDuplicates                           3 calls
1>        0 ms  FindUnderPath                              7 calls
1>        0 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides   1 calls
1>        0 ms  CheckForDuplicateFrameworkReferences       1 calls
1>        0 ms  ProcessFrameworkReferences                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                          2 calls
1>        0 ms  Message                                    3 calls
1>        0 ms  CheckForDuplicateItems                     3 calls
1>        1 ms  GetAssemblyVersion                         1 calls
1>        1 ms  CallTarget                                 3 calls
1>        1 ms  GetRestoreProjectStyleTask                 1 calls
1>        1 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.GetSourceLinkUrl   1 calls
1>        1 ms  ResolveAppHosts                            1 calls
1>        1 ms  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.MapSourceRoots   1 calls
1>        1 ms  CheckForDuplicateNuGetItemsTask            1 calls
1>        1 ms  CheckForUnsupportedWinMDReferences         1 calls
1>        1 ms  Hash                                       3 calls
1>        2 ms  WriteCodeFragment                          1 calls
1>        2 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.GitLab.GetSourceLinkUrl   1 calls
1>        2 ms  ResolvePackageFileConflicts                1 calls
1>        2 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git.GetSourceLinkUrl   1 calls
1>        2 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.Bitbucket.Git.GetSourceLinkUrl   1 calls
1>        2 ms  GetPackageDirectory                       10 calls
1>        2 ms  CopyRefAssembly                            1 calls
1>        3 ms  Copy                                       3 calls
1>        3 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.Common.GenerateSourceLinkFile   1 calls
1>        4 ms  WriteLinesToFile                           6 calls
1>        5 ms  Delete                                     4 calls
1>        5 ms  ResolveTargetingPackAssets                 1 calls
1>        7 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   1 calls
1>       19 ms  GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles          1 calls
1>       47 ms  CreateAppHost                              1 calls
1>       57 ms  Csc                                        1 calls
1>       58 ms  GenerateDepsFile                           1 calls
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Rebuild completed at 14:53 and took 00,400 seconds ==========
```

Project/Target Performance Summary is included, which is exactly what I/we want. If my colleague builds the solution on his computer using also VS 2022, he doesn't get the Performance Summary?

We already checked and compared a lot of settings inside Visual Studio, but we can't find the difference between his VS and my VS.

Of course, we could change the setting `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `diagnostic` or something like that, but then the output is way too verbose (and maybe slow). I have it on "Minimal" and still get the Performance Summary.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how you are getting the summary. Do you have either a `MSBuild.rsp` or `Directory.Build.rsp` file that may be setting the `-detailedSummary` switch? Are you somehow aliasing `msbuild` to `msbuild -ds`?

Comment: You can take a look of my answer, I am able to reproduce your situation, it should be no related to the setting you mentioned. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your situation:

[image]

You can see that 'MSBuild project build output verbosity' is minimal on my side, but still many output.

The problem should comes from this settings on your side:

[image]